# Bind terraform module in main.tf file

Tags: terraform

I have one terraform.tf file. 
In this file have 3 different modules: ec2, elb and rds. All the 3 modules have 3 different files like main.tf, variable.tf and output.tf.

How to bind these 3 modules in main.tf file?

Comment: What do you mean with "bind"?

Answer (score 0):

There is no concept of main.tf file in terraform. The binding of various modules is done by [output variables](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/outputs.html) and [remote state resources](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/terraform/d/remote_state.html). As quoted [here](https://www.terraform.io/docs/enterprise/guides/recommended-practices/part1.html).

> infrastructure code can be split into smaller Terraform configurations, which have limited scope and are owned by specific teams. These independent configurations use output variables to publish information and remote state resources to access output data from other workspaces.